# Why do I lose network connectivity for a virtual machine outside /24?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, subnet, netmask

I have a bunch of virtual machines (Ubuntu Server 14.04) hosted on a single real server (Ubuntu Server 14.04 with KVM). The number of virtual machines grow, and I'll soon have more than 254 of them.

To test,

1. I changed in `/etc/network/interfaces` of the real server the netmask from `255.255.255.0` to `255.255.254.0`. The IP address of the real server is `192.168.1.30`.
2. I did the similar operation with `virsh net-edit default`, which changed the netmask of `virbr0` to `255.255.254.0`.
3. I changed the netmask of the switch to `255.255.254.0` as well.
4. I changed the configuration of the test virtual machine like this:

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.2.35
   netmask 255.255.254.0
   network 192.168.1.0
   broadcast 192.168.2.255
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   dns-nameservers 192.168.1.13
   dns-search example.com
   ```

This is the current state:

1. I can't ping `192.168.2.35` from the real server: it is just stuck at "PING 192.168.2.35 (192.168.2.35) 56(84) bytes of data." When stopped (Ctrl+C), it complains: "143 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 142134ms".
2. The virtual machine `192.168.2.35` can't ping anything (neither the switch, nor the real server, nor google.com), throwing "connect: Network is unreachable" error for the first two, or "ping: unknown host google.com" for the last one.
3. The virtual machine can ping itself.

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Your subnet mask needs to be 255.255.255.252 (/22).

Comment: @joeqwerty: I'm sorry, I don't understand why. [As I understand it](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1878.txt), /22 corresponds to 255.255.252.0, while 255.255.255.252 would be /30. Also, why /22 if I only need 512 addresses? I've read [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](http://serverfault.com/q/49765/39827), but still don't get it. Can you please explain it in more details in an answer?

Comment: Looks like `255.255.252.0` is the right answer: I can ping the virtual machine, and it can ping the switch and the real server. I still don't understand why /22 instead of /23.

Comment: Work them both out here: http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/ip-subnet-calculator.php

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Comment: oops. I just noticed a typo in my first comment. It should have been 255.255.252.0. Sorry. It looks like you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I still don't understand why /22 instead of /23

Because you have calculated your subnets wrong, and you are trying to use IPs from two different subnets.

Or to put it a different way, if you use a /23 bit mask your starting address for the range, must be the first address for that range.  192.168.1.1 is not a starting address for any network described by a 23 bit mask, because that is just how the math works out.

With a 23 bit mask the valid networks are the following.

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.0.0/23
Address:   192.168.0.0          11000000.10101000.0000000 0.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.254.0 = 23   11111111.11111111.1111111 0.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.1.255            00000000.00000000.0000000 1.11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.0.0/23       11000000.10101000.0000000 0.00000000
HostMin:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.0000000 0.00000001
HostMax:   192.168.1.254        11000000.10101000.0000000 1.11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255        11000000.10101000.0000000 1.11111111
Hosts/Net: 510

$ ipcalc 192.168.2.0/23
Address:   192.168.2.0          11000000.10101000.0000001 0.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.254.0 = 23   11111111.11111111.1111111 0.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.1.255            00000000.00000000.0000000 1.11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.2.0/23       11000000.10101000.0000001 0.00000000
HostMin:   192.168.2.1          11000000.10101000.0000001 0.00000001
HostMax:   192.168.3.254        11000000.10101000.0000001 1.11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.3.255        11000000.10101000.0000001 1.11111111
Hosts/Net: 510
```

In your interface configuration though you seem to have `address 192.168.2.35`, and `gateway 192.168.1.1`.  Given that mask your gateway and address are on completely separate subnets.  Of course your broadcast and network address settings are also incorrect.

If you use a 22 bit mask you will get a range that includes 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x.  Be warned that your broadcast, and network values are still wrong, they also need to be fixed.

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.2.0/22
Address:   192.168.2.0          11000000.10101000.000000 10.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.252.0 = 22   11111111.11111111.111111 00.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.3.255            00000000.00000000.000000 11.11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.0.0/22       11000000.10101000.000000 00.00000000
HostMin:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.000000 00.00000001
HostMax:   192.168.3.254        11000000.10101000.000000 11.11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.3.255        11000000.10101000.000000 11.11111111
Hosts/Net: 1022
```